# Finding IDs in one table not in another

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

table1

```
ID    | Name     |    Code
 1       Joe          123
 2       Sam          674
 3       Mike         321
```

table2

```
ID    | User Name|    Code
 1        Joe         123
 2        Sam         674 
 3       Mike         321
 4       John         457
 5        Tim         235
```

Desired result:

```
4|John|457
5| Tim|235
```

Tabe1 and table2 code is identical. Table 1 code is a new field added thus contains no data for any record. Using the IDs as keys I took the codes from table2 and populated them in table1. However table1 has considerably less IDs then table2 so table2 has more codes then table1. I want to query which codes did not get transferred to table1. I thought it would be as simple as:

```
select *
from table2 t2
where t2.Code is not null and
      t2.Code not in (select t1.Code from table1 t1 where t1.Code is not null);
```

This returns nothing which is strange to me. What do I need to adjust in this query? This is for oracle.

Comment: sample input and output would speak a lot that long english sentences

Comment: All the codes appear in at least one row.  Is that surprising?

Comment: Added data and desired result

Comment: @GordonLinoff Say table2 had 2000 records and table1 had 1000. Lets say table1 is a subset of table2. I want to find the records that didn't match based on code.

Comment: Does `code` have any constraints on it? / can it be repeated for different users?

Comment: @JoeMalpass code is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the following:

```
SELECT t2.*
  FROM table2 t2
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1
                     WHERE t1.code = t2.code );
```

Comment: This worked. Looks like the record returned matched up with the count difference. So i'm just curious how come not in didn't work? If I did the reversal and checked codes in table1 that matched table2 it would work. So how come the opposite doesn't?

Comment: I don't know why your query didn't work. Does `select t1.Code from table1 t1 where t1.Code is not null` return anything on its own?